# unable to allow IP in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

i'm using IP Address And Domain Restrictions in IIS, trying to allow just one IP, but from that IP I cannot access the site also.

[image]

Comment: That's a typical mistake by beginners to use a Deny rule that blocks all incoming requests. The right way has been discussed in many places, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/631564/securing-and-restricting-access-to-iis-websites-to